# Text Pass word Security

Tags: security, text, passwords

Hello anyone knows how security is provided to text password in Google or in any website. In my web-app  i am encrypting password using AES algo. Should i need provide more security? If yes what kind of security is needed? How text passwords are managed/ made secure by Google or any web site?

Comment: I'm too lazy, but can someone did out a duplicate?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords

Answer (score 3):

Do not encrypt passwords.

Instead, you should *hash* passwords using a slow salted hash, preferably bcrypt or scrypt.

Answer (score 0):

You should secure your forms (also username and password fields in Login or Registration forms in HTTP transactions) and also the important data(s) in your database by hashing them with **SHA-1** or **MD5** algorithm (with salt)

For your login and registration forms you should use SSL connection in order to prevent **man-in-the-middle** and also **sniffing** attacks.

Comment: Correct. I forgot to mention that

Comment: Even with salt they suck, because they're too fast.

Comment: Yeah,  both sha1 and md5 are broken and even if they where ideal they are poor choices for password storage.  I would normally downvote a suggestion like this.